# Image Grid not Loading Images (Ionic + AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, image, ionic-framework

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/) to load some images in a grid with ionic framework and angularjs. When I use the code below the images are displayed correctly.

```
<ion-view title="Fotos ..." id="page8" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div class="row responsive-md">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img ng-src="http://localhost/dashboard/{{image.FILE}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I get the images from a json file with index named FILE= {"FILE":"path to image"} and the $scope storing the array is

> $scope.images = $state.params.dataToFotos.album;

"album" stores the arrays:

```
Object {item: Object, album: Array[2]}
album: Array[2]
0: Object
  $$hashKey: "object:75"
  FILE: "images/Sabado - Show/flyer-templates04.jpg"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
   $$hashKey: "object:76"
   FILE: "images/Sabado - Show/images.jpg"
```

When I update my div to the code below I am not able to load the images and nothing is displayed

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 3].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I fix it to include my source array to display the images? I tried to remove .src to my arrays but it did not work.

Page controller:

```
.controller('fotos2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(event, viewData){
    viewData.enableBack = true;
  });

if(!$state.params.dataToFotos) {
    console.log($state.params.dataToFotos);

}else{

    console.log($state.params.dataToFotos);
    $scope.images = $state.params.dataToFotos.album; 

}

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to inject a "src" property into the src attribute of the img elements.

But none of the objects in Album have a "src" property. They have a "FILE" property. Shouldn't they look like this:

```
<img ng-src="http://localhost/dashboard/{{images[$index].FILE}}" width="100%" />
```

Comment: Thank you man! I had done that before but it should have an error in another place of the code.